# Duplicate row in mysql database issue

Tags: java, mysql, database

I've checked similar answers on SO and mostly they recommend using resultset to check if the entry already exists in database. Not sure what i am doing wrong here

```
      public void setMonitorData(String name, monitorData data){
    Statement stmt = null;
    PreparedStatement stmtInsert;
    PreparedStatement stmtUpdate;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    for(int i = 0; i<data.wiredVector.size(); i++){
        if(data.wiredVector.elementAt(i).getInterfaceName().equals(name)){

            try{
                String checkRecord = "SELECT * FROM list_A WHERE NAME = '" + name + "'";
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(checkRecord);

                if(!rs.next()){  
                    String insertData = "INSERT INTO list_A (NAME, mac_add, ip_add,  default_gateway,"
                            + " net_add, mask, broad_add, max_transfer_rate, curr_transfer_rate,"
                            + " curr_used_bandwidth, packet_error_rate )"
                            + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

                 //preparedStatemend code here....

         else{
              String update = "UPDATE list_A SET ..."       

         .....
         }
```

After i execute the code..in the database there are dublicate records as if it skipped the condition entirely

Comment: can you please explain what is the actual issue, what exception you get

Comment: After i execute the code in the database there are dublicate records when normally they shouldnt

Comment: You must be executing the insert statement multiple times, otherwise it is not at all chance of having bug of `MySQL`.

Comment: @Stelsavva On what parameter you are confirming that you have duplicate records?

Comment: @smit the entire rows are inserted twice

Comment: @Stelsavva I got that part, What I didnt understand that where are you confirming that you already have record and should not be inserted or I am misunderstand that same sql inserts same record twice.

Comment: I think you might have a database design problem. Also, why are you not using prepared statements for the SELECT query?

Answer (score 1):

Here you take "if(!rs.next())" will moved to the past record.
So here it will start from one row before that's why it can allow duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT.. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE if mac_add has an unique index in your table or if it is a primary key.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here

```
if(!rs.next())
```

**javadocs :: 
ResultSet.next() Returns:**
true if the new current row is valid; false if there are no more rows

change it to

```
 if(rs.next())
```